# reading into a variable from a file

Tags: c, structure, file-handling

I read a program in a book wherein we have to read and write structures to file using fread and fwrite.

```
struct Address {
    int id;
    int set;
    char *name;
    char *email;
}

struct Database {
    int rows;             //number of rows
    struct Address *row;  //pointer to a row in the database
}

struct Connection {
    FILE *fp;
    struct Database *db
}
```

I allocate memory to all structures and initialize values for id and set in address structure and rows in database structure.

Then I write the structures onto a file.

```
int fc = fwrite(conn->db, sizeof(*conn->db->row) * number + sizeof(int), 1, conn->fp);
if(fc != 1) printf("Error");
```

Now I am trying to read the value of conn->db->rows from the file

```
int fc = fread(&conn->db->rows, sizeof(int), 1, conn->fp);
```

and I get a segmentation fault.

Now I am guessing this isn't the correct way to read a variable from file. 
Could anyone help me get this code working?

Comment: Sorry everyone. That was a typo :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have not read the document about fread.
please checkout it at [man fread](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread)

read file into buffer like this

```
int fc = fread(ptr, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
```

the **ptr** is the pointer to the memory where the file content read into.

Answer (score 1):

You need a plan on how you are going to write & read `struct Address`.  For brevity I'll ignore the `set` and `email` fields.   You need to decide how to demarcate your string, if at all. I've used a trailing `\n` for ease of using `fgets()`.  You need to determine if `int` is written/read as bytes (2,4,8,...) or ASCII characters.  OP example used `fwrite()`, I'd recommend fprintf() & "%d".

Of course, then call the functions `rows` times.

```
int WriteAddress(FILE *f, const struct Address *A) {
  size_t L = A->name ? (strlen(A->name) + 1) : 0;
  if ((1 != fwrite(&(A->id), sizeof(A->id), 1, f)) ||
     (L != fwrite(A->name, 1, L, f)) ||
     (1 != fwrite("\n", 1, 1, f))) {
    return  1; // failure
  }
  return 0; // No problem
}

int ReadAddress(FILE *f, struct Address *A) {
  A->id = 0;
  A->name = 0;
  #define MAXNAME (1000)
  char buf[MAXNAME+1];
  if (1 != fread(&(A->id), sizeof(A->id), 1, f)) return 1; // error
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f) == NULL) return 1; // error
  A->name = strdup(buf);  // could check for NULL here
  return 0;
}
```

A robust solution is non-trivial - depending on your error checking: max string lengths, differing `int` ranges on writer and reader, how to handle non-printable chars in a name, file errors, memory freeing, NULL names, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I think I am still not sure how fwrite works. 
Your code seems to suggest that instead of overwriting the file, it appends the data from the source to the end of the file. Am I right?

Comment: No. the above code writes the file a the current file pointer, then the file pointer is updated.  To insure appending only, open the file in append mode "a" or "a+".